# How to run Python script in VBA by reading the path in a cell?

Tags: python, vba

I need to close a project, but most people cannot configure VBA to change paths (path made the change).

```vb
Sub RunPython_Click()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PythonExe = Range("B13").Value
    PythonScript = Range("B14").Value
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & " " & PythonScript
End Sub
```

[image]

I'm doing this so people don't have to go into the VBA configuration to make the script path changes.

Comment: Please do not post images of code: you can copy/paste the code directly into the post and format it using the `{}` button.   What is the specific problem you're having with this task?  In the event either  of those paths might contain spaces, you should quote the paths in the call to `Run`

Comment: I need VBA to be able to read the path through the cell, i don't know if this code is correct.

Comment: Have you tried this?  That would be a good first step. You should really specify a worksheet though: something like `PythonExe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings").Range("B13").Value`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it this way, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very useful description of exactly what happens when you run your code.

Comment: Normally to let it work it is always necessary to leave it with 3 quotation marks to work, but even so putting it this way, it apparently shows the program running instantly, but the backend code does not work

Comment: try using the Shell() function:
call Shell(PythonExe & " " & PythonScript)

Comment: I would copy/paste your code with a suggested fix but it's a picture so...  Your paths shown do not have spaces though, s o it may be a problem with your python, such as implicit "current directory" for example.

Comment: @JoeBourne I tested it just now, it didn't work, it's still the same, it shows the program running instantly, and it doesn't run the python code.

Comment: @TimWilliams I made change, I put the VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```vb
Sub RunPython_Click()
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    'hard-coded for testing...
    PythonExe = "C:\Python\Python39-32\Python.exe"
    PythonScript = "C:\Python\Code\hello.py"
    
    ' /k keeps the window open so you can see any problems
    ' swap /k to /c when sure there's no errors
    Shell "cmd.exe /k """"" & PythonExe & """ """ & PythonScript & """""", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but what I need is to be able to collect the path from cell.

Comment: Note I have "for testing" in the comment above.  I assumed reading the paths from the cells wasn't the issue since you said the program "ran instantly".   Anyway, try it with hard-coded paths and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I understood it the wrong way.  Yes, this way it runs right along with the python codes.

Comment: But the error appeared: " C:\Python310\python.exe : can't open file" and " C:\\Project\\Script\\WorkScript.py," : [Error 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: are there double backslashes in the path you supplied?

Comment: No, they are normal, however in the cmd that was provided an error response showing the path of two slashes

Comment: So the error is in the Python script?

Comment: i don't think so, when i used with normal path,:                                                
           `PythonExe = """C:\Python\Python39-32\Python.exe"""
    PythonScript = """C:\Python\Code\hello.py"""` , it runs normally.