# Python script running from cmd but not from vba

Tags: python, vba

I have the following python script that deletes the blank line that appears when exporting an excel sheet as .txt and moves it to a different path

```
fd=open("D:\\Arturo\\Documentos\\8 Semestre\\Tutoreo\\Exportación como TXT VBA\\Trigger.txt","r")
d=fd.read()
fd.close()
m=d.split("\n")
s="\n".join(m[:-1])

fd=open("D:\\Arturo\\Documentos\\8 Semestre\\Tutoreo\\Exportación como TXT VBA\\Trigger.txt","w+")
for i in range(len(s)):
    fd.write(s[i])
fd.close()

import shutil
original = "D:\\Arturo\\Documentos\\8 Semestre\\Tutoreo\\Exportación como TXT VBA\\Trigger.txt"
target = "C:\\Users\\artur\\Desktop\\Trigger\\Trigger.txt"

shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

and this is how I call the script in vba

```
Sub eliminar_linea_py()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe""" 
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\artur\Desktop\py4e\remove_last_line.py" 
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    
End Sub
```

I'm working in the company computer and don't have admin permissions, when I try to run python script with VBA it doesn't work, how ever if I run the python script through command window it works perfectly, any idea of why this is happening and how could it be solved.

I have tried it in my personal laptop and vba its able to run the script without any issues.

Sorry for the long text, thank you for you time.

Comment: Maybe try a slightly different approach so you can see any errors which might be occurring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71446266/478884

Comment: thanks Tim, I'll get back next week and update